# C# interop services - using C dll - void*

Tags: c#, dllimport, void-pointers

I'm having trouble interoperating with a DLL written in C. I'm not sure what type of param to put in place of void*

This is how the API of given DLL looks like:

```
POSNET_API POSNET_STATUS __stdcall POS_SetDeviceParam  ( POSNET_HANDLE  hDevice,  
    unsigned long  paramCode,  
    void *  paramValue   
)
```

this is how I was trying to import it in C#:

```
[DllImport(EXT_DLL)]
private static extern int POS_SetDeviceParam(IntPtr hDevice, int POSNET_DEV_PARAM_IP, *type* paramValue);
```

in place of type I was putting:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string and other L*Str
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] char[] and other type of arrays including of type byte
IntPtr which where AllocHGlobal, GCHandle.Alloc allocated before
even preceeding the method with unsafe and type = void*, combining above alloc aso.
raw type: string, char[]...
```

I ran out of possibilities by myself.

paramValue should have a value of an IP in following format: "192.168.1.1" - this is how  it looks like in a C demo:

```
string ip="10.33.44.6";
POS_SetDeviceParam(hDevice,POSNET_DEV_PARAM_IP,(void*)ip.c_str());
```

In C# code, the hDevice is not being initialized - POS_SetDeviceParam should initialize it with additional params. 
Any suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521774/how-to-import-void-c-api-into-c

Comment: @ArnaudF.: letting paramValue be of type IntPtr and copying string to unmanaged memory doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Unsigned long should be UInt32 - check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms235282.aspx.

Comment: @weismat indeed UInt32 solved my problem, I appreciate your answer, thank you! <br/>
I have another extern method, which has an unsigned long too, where I'm passing an int and the method works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for all the suggestions, the code below solved my problem!

```
[DllImport(EXT_DLL)]
private static extern int POS_SetDeviceParam(IntPtr hDevice, UInt32 POSNET_DEV_PARAM_IP, IntPtr paramValue);

void Test() {
     POS_SetDeviceParam(new IntPtr(), 0x00020005, Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("192.168.1.1"));
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call FreeHGlobal after calling your fucnction

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use this P/Invoke signature:

```
[DllImport(EXT_DLL)]
private static extern int POS_SetDeviceParam(
    IntPtr hDevice, 
    int paramCode, 
    IntPtr paramValue
);
```

But you'll have to do some work to that string in order to pass it through the `IntPtr paramValue` argument.

Perhaps you can try using [Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx) as that will give you an `IntPtr` you can use. If using this method though be sure to free the memory once you've finished with it.

Comment: I've been trying Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi() already, before posting my question. Thanks!